# HP Jetdirect 175x and HP Officejet K7103 printsharing

Tags: windows, printing, network-printer, print-server

I have managed to get this setup working, but it is very unreliable and either the printserver or the printer seem to crash and won't respond after 1 or 2 prints.  I am able to still access the web config of the 175x.

I had a similar problem with a Linksys wireless print server and assumed that a HP print server would do the job better.

Anybody any ideas what to do next? It is not possible to flash the printserver, nor the printer as far as I know, so I assume I have some iffy settings in the print server config somewhre. All our users are on Win7 or Vista.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the printer, I have checked with HP's website and it does not list it, but the information is quite old. I'm assuming the printer is supported as it's an HP K7103 (fairly common business A3 officejet), also all the printer attributes such as page count, ink levels show in the web config - Its all very confusing!